# Android Icon Set Generation via Command Prompt

Tags: android

As we all know, in eclipse (*with ADT Plugin*) we have feature to create the Android Icon Set (*File->new->Android->Android Icon Set*)

Can this be invoked via command prompt?

*reason being*, we have lot of icons/images which we have to import to the project and if we could do it via command prompt then we can write a script which can do it..

can someone please throw some light on this..

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script to convert an SVG icon to multiple resolutions in a structured manner: https://gist.github.com/deepankarb/e69de4373ebd7067e0fc